# Find the nearest or the k nearest line to a given point using spatial index

Tags: python, scikit-learn, geopandas, knn, spatial-index

I have a layer of streets representing streets and some points which are specific events. I want to find the nearest (the first 4) street(s) to each event. My question is about indexing. I can use `sindex` on the line dataframe but I am not sure how I can index the points. At the moment, I am using a 100m offset for each point and create a bounding box and then do the intersect and calculate the distance. But I would prefer a solution where I do not manipulate the index for points. Since I have two big datasets for both line and points, I am looking for an efficient solution.

```
points_proj =  points.to_crs('EPSG:2952')
lines_proj =  lines.to_crs('EPSG:2952')

lines_proj.sindex

offset = 100
bbox = points_proj.bounds + [-offset, -offset, offset, offset]

hits = bbox.apply(lambda row: list(lines_proj.sindex.intersection(row)), axis=1)

tmp = pd.DataFrame({
# index of points table
"pt_idx": np.repeat(hits.index, hits.apply(len)),
# ordinal position of line - access via iloc later
"line_i": np.concatenate(hits.values)
})

# Join back to the lines on line_i; we use reset_index() to 
# give us the ordinal position of each line
tmp = tmp.join(lines_proj.reset_index(drop=True), on="line_i")

# Join back to the original points to get their geometry
# rename the point geometry as "point"
tmp = tmp.join(points_proj.geometry.rename("point"), on="pt_idx")

# Convert back to a GeoDataFrame, so we can do spatial ops
tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tmp, geometry="line_geom", crs=points_proj.crs)

tmp["snap_dist"] = tmp.geometry.distance(gpd.GeoSeries(tmp.point))
tmp["snap_dist"].sort_values()

# Discard any lines that are greater than tolerance from points
tmp_tolerance_100 = tmp.loc[tmp.snap_dist <= 100]
# Sort on ascending snap distance, so that closest goes to top
tmp_tolerance_100 = tmp_tolerance_100.sort_values(by=["snap_dist"])

# group by the index of the points and take the first, which is the
# closest line 
closest_tolerance_100 = tmp_tolerance_100.groupby("pt_idx").first()
# construct a GeoDataFrame of the closest lines
closest_tolerance_100 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(closest_tolerance_100, geometry="line_geom")
```

This solution is based on [snapping problem](https://medium.com/@brendan_ward/how-to-leverage-geopandas-for-faster-snapping-of-points-to-lines-6113c94e59aa).

I am basically looking for a solution where I do not need to define an offset for points.

```
offset = 100
bbox = points_proj.bounds + [-offset, -offset, offset, offset]
```

and something that is fast for two datasets where source is around 700,000 points and candidates are around 15000 lines.

I also saw an efficient [solution](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html) using scikitlearn and geopandas, but it's for two point layers.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and ideally provide a [mre]

Comment: @MichaelDelgado hope it's clear now.

Comment: awesome this is definitely helpful. ideal would be creating points and polygons with code but this is a great start. thanks!

Comment: No, thank you.
An emphasize is that I am trying to find the closest or the first 4 closest lines to each point. If I use PostGIS I do not need to define an offset or a tolerance distance for KNN. However it's been already 4 hours that my query in postgres is running. I wanted to do it with Balltree but had the problem with creating a radian version of my line geodataframe to fit the second solution.

Comment: is it the closest or do you need the 4 closest? if it's just the closest than `geopandas.sjoin_nearest` should do the trick nicely. 4 closest is trickier

Comment: the 4 closest, is the ideal one!

Comment: but I think something like what you're doing could work... something along the lines of `geopandas.sjoin(points.buffer(BUFFER), lines, how='left', predicate='intersects')` and then find the distances after joining and select the top 4.

Comment: this is assuming points and lines are both GeoDataFrames

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. The main purpose of all the nearest neighbor analysis here, is to determine a buffer size for lines at the end. In fact, I am trying to explore the distribution of distances between points and lines, and later, see their relationships with other attributes of lines and points. It allows me to find out how far from a line I should go to capture most of the points. That's why I do not want to apply an offset or in your solution the buffer. I am trying to find a solution that is efficient based on indexing.

Comment: I see. a counterpoint would be that if you set an overly generous buffer, you can quickly identify the points to consider using sjoin, and then work on narrowing down your list. the benefit of this approach is that the spatial indexing in sjoin is all written in C and is in general very fast compared with anything that can be written in python, or which involves calling geopandas spatial ops many times. so there may be a practical reason to use a less efficient algorithm here because pure python is so slow compared with geopandas.

Comment: Thanks for your points. I will try the buffer and see how it performs. Thanks. @MichaelDelgado I also see the solution (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/301935/20175), but having difficulties to exchange the first and second geodataframe! The solution is for closest points to lines, but I am looking for closest lines to point. Do you think it's a solution to work on?

Comment: geopandas has had a ton of work to vectorize & rewrite the algorithms since that post. I think you'll find sjoin and sjoin_nearest are your fastest options, and they can join lines to points no problem